# RabbitMQ and RabbitMQBundle routing keys configuration to multi consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, symfony4

I'm using RabbitMqBundle in Symfomy4.

What i would like to achieve is to publish a message (a notification in my case) and by a routing key choose if to store the message in Db or send it by email or both.

I'm focused on **topic** exchange but i can't figure out how to reach this goal, maybe i didn't understand completely the mechanism of RabbitMQ, but i'm completely new to it.

This is my configuration

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
  connections:
    default:
      #url: '%env(RABBITMQ_URL)%'
      url: 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672'
      vhost:    '/'
      lazy:     false
      connection_timeout: 3
      read_write_timeout: 3
  producers:
    notifications:
      connection: default
      exchange_options: {name: 'notifications', type: topic}
  consumers:
    store_notifications:
      connection: default
      exchange_options: {name: 'notifications', type: topic}
      queue_options:
        name: 'notifications'
        routing_keys:
        - 'notification.store'
        # - 'notification.*' # this will match everything
      callback: App\Consumer\Notification\DbHandler
    email_notifications:
      connection: default
      exchange_options: {name: 'notifications', type: topic}
      queue_options:
        name: 'notifications'
        routing_keys:
        - 'notification.email'
      callback: App\Consumer\Notification\EmailHandler
```

In this case i can publish a message just to one of the routing key: **notification.store** or **notification.email**

I would like to have something like publish($msg, ['notification.store', 'notification.email']), but i know i can make a **consumer** listen to multiple routing keys and with wildcard but i can't figure out how to configure it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do by:

- If you just want to store DB, the routing key is: notification.store
- If you just want to send email, the routing key is: notification.email
- If you want to do both, the routing key is: notification.both

Then, your queue should bound to the exchange with these routing keys:

- store_notifications: [notification.store, notification.both]
- email_notifications: [notification.email, notification.both]

By doing this, if the message with routing `notification.store` just go to `store_notifications`, `notification.email` just go to `email_notifications`. But message with routing `notification.both` goes to both queues.

Configuration:

```
  consumers:
    store_notifications:
      connection: default
      exchange_options: {name: 'notifications', type: topic}
      queue_options:
        name: 'notifications'
        routing_keys:
        - 'notification.store'
        - 'notification.both'
      callback: App\Consumer\Notification\DbHandler
    email_notifications:
      connection: default
      exchange_options: {name: 'notifications', type: topic}
      queue_options:
        name: 'notifications'
        routing_keys:
        - 'notification.email'
        - 'notification.both'
      callback: App\Consumer\Notification\EmailHandler
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additionally, you'll want to have different types of consumers (i.e. one for database, one for email) pulling from these respective queues, in case that isn't obvious.